# python audio player filtered without jitter

Tags: python, audio

For a project I need to

- read WAV file
- filter
- play WAV file

The code below is "working" except that the sound crackles, and that is because I can't guarantee a continue data stream to the audio output. Filtering takes some time and that's where the sound freezes for a very short time.

In the future I'd like to do some extra calculations on the raw audio data. I'd like to know which method is the best to keep the sound smooth.

```py
import pyaudio  
import wave  
from scipy import signal
from struct import *

chunk = 1024

f = wave.open("sample.wav","rb")  
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

stream = p.open(format = p.get_format_from_width(f.getsampwidth()),  
            channels = f.getnchannels(),  
            rate = f.getframerate(),  
            output = True)  

data = f.readframes(chunk)
b, a = signal.butter(2, 0.01)

tmp = len(data)/2
s = '<'
for i in range(0,tmp):
    s = s + 'h'

while data != '':
    sig = signal.filtfilt(b, a, unpack(s,data))

    output_signal = pack(s,*sig)
    stream.write(output_signal) 
    data = f.readframes(chunk)

stream.stop_stream()  
stream.close()  
p.terminate()
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you need to filter in real-time, or can you collect the output signals and write them together?

Comment: you should think of buffering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try splitting the producer of the data and the consumer (which is pyaudio) in two programs, with a regular Unix pipe connecting them.  The Unix pipe plays the role of buffering.  Example:

in producer.py:

```
while data != '':
    sig = signal.filtfilt(b, a, unpack(s,data))
    output_signal = pack(s,*sig)
    sys.stdout.write(output_signal)      # <===
    data = f.readframes(chunk)
```

in consumer.py:

```
while 1:
    data = sys.stdin.read(1024)
    if not data: break
    stream.write(data)
```

Command-line invocation:

```
python producer.py | python consumer.py
```

If it works, then you can also run `python consumer.py` from inside the other program with `os.popen()`, for example.

Comment: I should also mention that you can get the same effect using two threads instead of two processes, and not using an OS pipe but for example the `queue` module.  It's more complex though, and has no benefit I can think of in your case.  It main advantage would be if the two processes needed to exchange more than just a stream of bytes.